# WPF TouchEvents- capturing very first touchdown

Tags: wpf, events, touch, delay

I've got a WPF touch application that's working pretty well apart from one thing: capturing the event that's fired when a user first touches an element. TouchDown doesn't seem to work, at least not without a significant delay. TouchEnter works fine when a user slides their finger onto the element, but when they first put their finger onto it there is a significant delay before any event is fired. I need the element to respond pretty much immediately, so any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to add to the XAML for the control: Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"

```
<Image Name="image" Source="images\animage.jpg" Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: I don't want to take the credit but its more readable when its written as an answer...